# Concatenate multiple strings into single msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

via the below code I have a number of validation steps. Currently if a user omits 1 or more data inputs and or inputs incorrectly data they are getting multiple msgboxes. Not a great UI experience, what I'm looking to do is to concatenate these strings into a single msgbox. Bear in mind I'm unable to do so using System.Text etc to generate a string builder using append.

I'm relatively new to vba so if you do post any comments or feedback if you could explain it as fully as possible.

```
Public Function ValidateMe(strAccNum As String, iDte As Integer, strTRS As String, strPrem As String) As Boolean
    ' Function tests each input passed to it and validates it. If there is an issue the user is notified with a message box.
    Dim blnValAcc As Boolean
    Dim blnValDte As Boolean
    Dim blValTRS As Boolean
    Dim blnValPrem As Boolean
    Dim blnValidOverall As Boolean

    ' Default to Invalid
    blnValAcc = False
    blnValDte = False
    blnValTRS = False
    blnValPrem = False
    blnValidOverall = False

    ' Validate Account Number
    Dim strMessage As String
    Dim strSortCode As String
    strMessage = ""
    strSortCode = Left(strAccNum, 6)

    ' AccNum must be 14 characters long and all characters must be numeric
    If (Len(strAccNum) = 14 And (IsNumeric(strAccNum) = True)) Then
        blnValAcc = True
    Else:
        strMessage = strMessage & vbNewLine & "Account Number must be 14 characters long and contain only numeric characters."
    End If

    ' 8 and 10 digit account nubmers cannot have a due date change
    If (Len(strAccNum) = (8 Or 10) And (IsNumeric(strAccNum) = True)) Then
        blnValAcc = False
        strMessage = strMessage & vbNewLine & "8 and 10 digit account numbers cannot have a due date change."
    End If

    ' Checks sort code against list of sort codes if the accout number has already passed previous tests
    If blnValAcc = True Then
        blnValAcc = CheckSortCode(strSortCode)
        If blnValAcc = False Then
            strMessage = strMessage & "Check sort code."
        End If
    End If

    If blnValAcc = False Then
        MsgBox strMessage, , "Check Account Number"
    End If

    ' Validate new Due Date
    If (iDte >= 1 And iDate <= 31) Then
        blnValDte = True
    Else:
        blnValDte = False
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid due date, a number between 1 and 31", , "Invalid Date"
    End If

    If ((strTRS = "Yes") Or (strTRS = "No")) Then
        blnValTRS = True
    End If

    ' Validate strPrem
    If strPrem = "Yes" Then
        blnValPrem = True
    Else:
        MsgBox "Customer must be advised of how change may affect premiums.", , "Premium Changes"
    End If

    ' Validate strTRS
    If strTRS = "" Then
        valTRS = False
        MsgBox "Please select an option from the drop down menu.", , "Customer has been advised of TRS implications?"
    End If

    If ((blnValAcc = True) And (blnValDte = True) And (blnValTRS = True) And (blnValPrem = True)) Then
        blnValidOverall = True
    End If

    ' Function returns true or false
    ValidateMe = blnValidOverall

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic pattern:

```
Dim msg as string

If someProblem1 then
    msg = msg & iif(len(msg) > 0, vbLf, "") & "Problem1 description"
end if

if someProblem2 then
    msg = msg & iif(len(msg) > 0, vbLf, "") & "Problem2 description"
end if

'etc etc


'done testing...
if len(msg) > 0 then
    msgbox "There are some problems with your submission:" & vbLf & vbLf & msg,, "Oops"

end if

ValidateMe = (Len(msg) = 0)
```

Comment: I particularly like the "Oops". Think there might be a typo on that line `msg,,`.

Comment: Haha. Thanks Tim, much appreciated. I’m pretty sure n00b butt can use this. Much appreciated.

Comment: My mistake Tim.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams I'm trying to implement this into my above code but unfortunately I cant seem to get it to work. Some pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does it do instead of work?  Can you update your question to add what you tried?

Comment: Basically do not show a messagebox until you're done with the full validation.  This does mean you can only use a single messagebox title though (not one per check as you have above)